# Get the sum of specific ID mysql with different types and name

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to get the sum of all checks but with different types and name and I'm having trouble in getting the sum for all of them. 
I have a **transaction amount** and a **discounted amount**. I want to get the sum of the two transactions so that I can get my Estimated Total.
Take note that I have different kinds of transactions that also have different types of discount and transaction amount(e.g 20% discount, 5% discount).

So, far what I got going through my query are only the first two records which has **Check 201**  that has the amount of **85**. However, I also want to get the other transaction which has the **Check 301**. Thus, getting the estimated total amount of **225**.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Here's my sample data.**
[image]

**Here's my query:**

```
select a.DATE, a.ID, SUM(a.amount) as TRANSACTION, 
(select sum(cashier.amount) from cashier where `cashier `.`check` = 
a.`check` and cashier.date = a.date  and  cashier.ID= a.ID GROUP BY 
`cashier.check) as `ESTIMATED VALUE`  FROM cashier a where a.date = 
'8/1/2017' and a.name = 'Price discounted 10%' GROUP BY a.DATE, a.ID ORDER BY a.date
```

Comment: *However, I also want to get the other transaction which has the Check 301* why can you explain it or provide a reason/criteria to do that

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid i dont know what explanation you are talking about... but I just want to get my estimated total for all discounted price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case expression` to treat amount as either positive or negative (for the discounts) then just sum that.

```
SELECT
      a.`date`
    , a.ID
    , SUM(a.amount) AS `transaction`
    , SUM(case when type <> 1 then a.amount*-1.0 else a.amount end) AS `estmated_value`
FROM cashier a
WHERE a.date = '2017-01-08'
AND a.name = 'Price discounted 10%'
GROUP BY
      a.`date`
    , a.ID
ORDER BY
      a.`date`
```